# Is it possible combine columns in MySQL in a top down format?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the largest datetime between 2 columns on different tables, to compare it against another column in a separate table.

I eventually came across the SQL concat(), but realised that it is more for use cases like concatenating names together.

Just wondering if it would be possible for concat() to return a result as follows below, that allows me to call the newly combined column to compare against the third column.

| Col 1 | Col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| no1.1 | no2.1 |
| no1.2 | no2.2 |

| Combined Columns Result (End Goal) |
| --- |
| no1.1 |
| no1.2 |
| no2.1 |
| no2.2 |

Instead of the normal concat() function where it just ends up being
| Combined Columns Result |
|:-:|
|no1.1 no2.1|
|no1.2 no2.2|

Comment: Use UNION, not CONCAT().

Comment: @Akina Thank you so much, I've been trying to avoid UNION as I saw that they mostly combined 2 tables together, but I did not know that I could combine 2 columns together in this way.

Comment: @IsThisKaii Your comment makes no sense. I've been trying to avoid air, as I see that oxygen is frequently used in explosions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a union with a computed column to maintain the order of each column:

```sql
SELECT col
FROM
(
    SELECT col1 AS col, 1 AS src FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col2, 2 FROM yourTable
) t
ORDER BY src, col;
```

Comment: Would I then be able to call the unionized columns to use afterwards? Since thats the end goal of my query, to compare the biggest of the two columns to a third column

Comment: I have answered the question you actually ask (which is different than your comment above).  Broadly speaking, yes, you should be able to use the approach in my answer for your other problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think that I was not very clear in my initial question posted. I will try to work towards my end goal using your answer as a reference. :)